# 1050: Cannot assign to a non-reference value

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

Hi my code as fallows what is wrong with it?
thank you and sorry for my bad english.

```
protected function belgelerDG_itemClickHandler(event:ListEvent):void
        {

            var durum:Boolean = false;
            if(belgeicerikWindow==null){
                belgeicerikWindow=new belgeicerik();
                belgeicerikWindow.title=belgelerDG.selectedItem.belge;
                belgeicerikWindow.open();
            }
            else{
                durum=false;
                for ( var i:int = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.openedWindows.length - 1; i >= 0; --i ) {
                    if(NativeApplication.nativeApplication.openedWindows[i].title.toString() == belgeicerikWindow.title=belgelerDG.selectedItem.belge){
                        belgeicerikWindow.orderToFront();
                        durum=true;
                    }
                }

                if(durum==false){
                    belgeicerikWindow=new belgeicerik();
                    belgeicerikWindow.title=belgelerDG.selectedItem.belge;
                    belgeicerikWindow.open();
                }

            }


        }
```

Comment: In order to ask a good question you have to **1)** say how it *should* work **2)** say how it *actually* works **3)** say what have you tried so far. Right now is difficult for people reading your question understand what's the problem

Comment: It's not clear what 1050 means. Is it a line number? Is it an error code?

Comment: sorry my english is not good enough to tell what i am trying to do. but 1050 is error code i gues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm betting the problem lies with the if statement that starts with:

```
if(NativeApplication.nativeApplication.openedWindows[i].title.toString()
```

You are doing an assignment within the value you are trying to compare against:

```
 == belgeicerikWindow.title=belgelerDG.selectedItem.belge)
```

If it isn't what is causing your problem, at least it is something you should fix to make things more legible.  :)